# inserting an underscore into a particular part of variable names R

Tags: r

I'd like to insert an underscore after the first three characters of all variable names in a data frame. Any help would be much appreciated.

Current data frame:

```
df1 <- data.frame("genCrc_b1"=c(1,1,1),"genprd"=c(1,1,1) ,"genopr_b1_b2"=c(1,1,1))
```

Desired data frame:

```
df2 <- data.frame("gen_Crc_b1"=c(1,1,1),"gen_prd"=c(1,1,1) ,"gen_opr_b1_b2"=c(1,1,1))
```

My attempts:

```
gsub('^(.{3})(.*)$', "_", names(df1))
gsub('^(.{3})(.*)$', '\\_\\2', names(df1))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `sub` to capture the first 3 characters as a group (`(.{3})`) and in the replacement specify the backreference of the group (`\\1`) followed by underscore

```
names(df1) <- sub("^(.{3})", "\\1_", names(df1))
names(df1)
#[1] "gen_Crc_b1"    "gen_prd"       "gen_opr_b1_b2"
```

---

In the OP's post, especially the last one, there were two capture groups, but only one was specified

```
gsub('^(.{3})(.*)$', '\\1_\\2', names(df1))
```

BTW, `gsub` is not needed as we are replacing only at a single instance instead of multiple times.

In the first case, none of backreference for the captured groups were used in the replacement

Answer (score 2):

If your variable names all begin with `gen`, we can also do the following.

```
colnames(df1) <- gsub("gen", "gen_", colnames(df1), fixed = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `regmatches<-` to replace the sub-expressions.

```
regmatches(names(df1), regexpr("gen", names(df1), fixed=TRUE)) <- "gen_"
```

Now, check that the values have been properly changed.

```
names(df1)
[1] "gen_Crc_b1"    "gen_prd"       "gen_opr_b1_b2"
```

Here, `regexpr` finds the first position in each element of the character vector that matches the subexpression, "gen". These positions are fed to `regmatches` and the substitution is performed.